# Interpreting a vector solution geometrically

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I was doing a STEP paper (Paper 3 1995) and I got to the last part of question 8 (interpreting the last equation geometrically) given in

[image]

Could someone suggest how to interpret the last equation geometrically and the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Well, what’s the geometric interpretation of a dot product vanishing? What comes to mind when you see the square of a vector (which I assume is shorthand for the dot product with itself)?

Comment: @amd thanks for responding. For the vanishing (asuming you mean it becoming zero) it is when two vectors are perpendicular, however, in this case is it really vanishing as $p_1$ and $p_2$ are scalers not vectors which means that $n_1 · r_2$ doesn't have to vanish. In regards to the square of a vectors I think of the vector dotted with itself which is the same as the lenght of the vector squared. However, again, doesn't $n_1 · r_1$ give a scaler rather than a vector?

Comment: Yes, I misinterpreted the last equation. However, it can still be interpreted in terms of certain signed distances. In particular, what is the distance of the plane $\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf n=p$ from the origin? What distance does $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf r$ represent if $\mathbf n$ is a unit vector?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding again. Is it $RHS = ((r_1-r_2)⋅n_1))^2$ which is the same as the distance between the plane and $r_2$. Thus doing this for both sides, and interpreting it, meaning that the distance to $r_2$ from $\pi_1$ is the same as the distance from $\pi_2$ to $r_1$. Is this correct?